# How to check if user has selected a property in <select> and add it to the search query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, select, drop-down-menu

I'm getting JSON data from weather API. Currently my code gets town name from an html input and queries the API to get weather for that  particular place. I have introduced a select element for country codes (so if you want to check the weather in Naples USA rather than Naples Italy you have to select the US code in the dropdown menu). 
I want it to check if there has been a country code selected before firing off the search, and if so add that into the parameters of the query.

I have tried some if/else statements with no success. The country codes are stored in an object and aren't hard-coded. Im getting the object from different API. I have managed to put those codes into the select element, but now I need to make sure the search considers if a different country region has been selected.

I would like the region variable to take in the country code, if user has selected one

```js
// CODE THAT ADDS WEATHER DATA INTO DOM //


$("#weather-button").click(function() {
  $(".weather-img").html("");
  $(".weather-type").html("");
  $(".weather-temp").html("");

  var city = $("input[name=city-box]").val();
  var region = "";

  $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + region + "&units=metric&myapikey", function(data) {
    console.log(data);..........................
  });

  // HOW IM GETTING COUNTRY CODE DATA //
  var countryCodes = [];

  $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function(countryData) {

    var countryCodes = countryData.reduce((countries, item) => {
      countries[item.name] = item.alpha2Code;
      return countries;
    }, {});
    console.log(countryCodes);
    // HOW IVE ADDED COUNTRY CODE DATA TO THE <SELECT> // 
    var selectBox = $("#country-select");
    var select = document.getElementById("country-select");

    selectBox.append($('<option>', {
      value: -1,
      text: 'Select a Country'
    }));
    for (index in countryCodes) {
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(countryCodes[index], index);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Your code is very incomplete. It is not possible to guess what your issue is from the code posted. Where do `countryCodes` come from?

Comment: I thought it wasn't important as long as it worked and the data showed in the select dropdown. 
I've updated the code snippet, thank you @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan I'm new to all of this, so I don't understand which loop you're refering to. To be fair there is a lot to read in the thread you marked as duplicate to my question, so I will take it on board and have a good read through it. Thank you

Comment: Because you had not closed your code, I posted a dupe which was not relevant to your question

Comment: Please find your answer below. Thanks for this question which made me think deeply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Sorry for my last answer which I posted blindly without testing. Also, without putting explanation. Thanks to the commenters.

By binding options using

```
for (index in countryCodes) {
   select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(countryCodes[index], index);
}
```

You will be getting "AF", "AX", "AL" .... so on in your dropdown.
Resulting for e.g "AF" to be value of the element and corresponding "Afghanistan" as text for the select element.

So, here is what @Rogozin you actually need:

```
$("#weather-button").click(function() {
  $(".weather-img").html("");
  $(".weather-type").html("");
  $(".weather-temp").html("");

  var city = $("input[name=city-box]").val();
  var region = "";
  var selected = document.getElementById("country-select");
  if (selected.value != -1) {
    region = selected.value; // if you want value "AF" to send
    // OR  
    region = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text; // if you want "Afghanistan" to send
  }

  $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + region + "&units=metric&myapikey", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I have tried putting the code at the beginning inside the $("#weather-button").click, outside of the scope and as well as inside of the  $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all" function - no success

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks HereticMonkey and nircraft !! @Rogozin, please use this answer for your problem. Let us know if it Works !!

Comment: It did! Thanks for coming back and editing the post as well as adding explanation. Marked your reply as the solution to my problem. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **onchange** property or **change event on jquery**

```
<form>
   Select Character:
   <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
     <option value="d">D</option>
   </select>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for this

```js
$.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function(countryData) {
  var countryCodes = countryData.map(item => `<option value="${item.alpha2Code}">${item.name}</option>`);
  $("#country-select")
    .html('<option value="">Country</option>')
    .append(countryCodes.join(""));
})

$("#country-select").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value)
})

$("#weather-button").click(function() {
  $(".weather-img").html("");
  $(".weather-type").html("");
  $(".weather-temp").html("");

  var city = $("input[name=city-box]").val();
  var region = $("#country-select").val() || "whatever is default country code";

  $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + region + "&units=metric&myapikey", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country-select"></select>
```